# How nutch scoring affects the score of existing urls in the CrawlDB?

Tags: nutch

I have a custom domain scoring plugin in Nutch that scores urls based on the score associated with a given domain. 
The question I have is that does it ever update the score of a url that is already present in the CrawlDB ?